# How to name template .php so it can show all custom posts of a specific taxonomy's term?

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have three custom post types.

1. Accessories
2. Watches
3. Jewelries

I have one taxonomy called "brands". I have created only one term, which is called "rolex".

I have created a single-product.php template file to be triggered when i hit for example :

```
www.mysite.com/watches/rolex/test
```

And it's working. (I have used rewrite - site.com/custom_post_type/taxonomy/posts_title)

I have created a template, to show all the custom post types under a specific term. For example if i hit this url :

```
www.mysite.com/watches/rolex
```

But the problem is that my template is not properly working - wordpress doesn't connect the url with the file. How should i name the template i created to be connected with the above url?

*I believe the url rewrite might cause a problem as i mentioned above - i call the `custom_post_type/custom_taxonomy_term/posts_title`

Comment: See this https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies

Comment: Thanks for the reference, i have already read that but can't find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file taxonomy-{taxonomy_slug}-{term_slug}.php for displaying the particular taxonomy term posts.

Your file name should be:

```
taxonomy-brands-rolex.php
```

And write your desired code for getting the posts.

And if still there is confusion, please see this link: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/

Hope, this may be helpful to you.

Comment: It doesn't work, it will load index.php. Plus i want that template to work not only with "rolex"  term but with any other term. Is it a problem due to the rewrite rule i have? (which calls `/custom_post_type/taxonomy/posts_name`) . Even if i name it taxonomy.php it won't work.

Comment: I think so, but this is only the way for creating a taxonomy term page.